# How to allow two taps on a custom UIView to show and hide a popover?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have three custom UIViews which are small circles and are placed at different locations on the screen. If you click any circle, it shows a popover. There are 2 scenarios:
1. If I click a circle it shows a popover, if I click it again it hides the popover as well as the circle.
2. If I click a circle it will show a popover, but if I don't click it back again and instead click another circle, it should show me the popover of the second circle and should hide the first popover and circle.
In short at a time there should be only one popover visible. I managed to get implement the first scenario but struggling with the second. Here's the code:

```
   func showPopover(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if sender.view == hotSpotOne{

        let description = "Search \n" + "Search equities to view the order book and market prints for specific moments in time."
        let heading = "Search"
        let wordRange = (description as NSString).rangeOfString(heading)
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: description, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)])
        attributedString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12)], range: wordRange)
        self.helpTip!.showAttributedText(attributedString, direction: .Down, maxWidth: 200, inView: self.view, fromFrame: self.hotSpotOne.frame)

        if self.helpTip!.isVisible {
            self.helpTip!.hide()
            hotSpotOne.removeFromSuperview()
            return
        }  
    }
    else if sender.view == hotSpotTwo{

        let description = "Market Events \n" + "Swipe to view recent market anomalies selected by Surveyor's analytics team."
        let heading = "Market Events"
        let wordRange = (description as NSString).rangeOfString(heading)
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: description, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)])
        attributedString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12)], range: wordRange)
        self.helpTip!.showAttributedText(attributedString, direction: .Down, maxWidth: 200, inView: self.view, fromFrame: self.hotSpotTwo.frame)



        if self.helpTip!.isVisible {
            self.helpTip!.hide()
            hotSpotTwo.removeFromSuperview()
            return
        }
    }
    else {

        let description = "Get More Data \n" + "Learn More about how Surveyor's professional products can benefit your financial institution."
        let heading = "Get More Data"
        let wordRange = (description as NSString).rangeOfString(heading)
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: description, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)])
        attributedString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12)], range: wordRange)
        self.helpTip!.showAttributedText(attributedString, direction: .Up, maxWidth: 200, inView: self.view, fromFrame: self.hotSpotThree.frame)

        if self.helpTip!.isVisible {
            self.helpTip!.hide()
            hotSpotThree.removeFromSuperview()
            return
        }

    }

}
```

I am using AMPopTip library to show the popovers. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Idk if I were you I'd add `singleTapGesture` to the custom view and maintain a count on it in gesture's delegate. I would distinguish between different senders based on sender's view's tag. And on every tap, I will single out the tap based on that tag, check its respective count and perform desired action.  But then again, I don't always use the best methods.

Comment: @NSNoob thank you for your reply, I also thought of doing by using view's tag, but all my views have the same tag number. Now if i change the tag on each view then i have to rewrite the code.